# Can Xposed Framework be run successfully alongside a custom rom?

Tags: custom-roms, xposed-framework, compatibility

I would like to know if Xposed Framework can successfully run alongside a custom rom that possesses many features or whether it has to be a stock ROM. I wasn't able to find a consensus on whether or not it was possible, so I attempted to try flashing Xposed on a Nexus 6 while running Benzo Rom (a feature rich AOSP ROM), but I was unsuccessful since I got stuck on the Google boot logo.

Comment: In general it's possible, although some modules can/will fail because custom ROMs modify the framework already... But it's not supported, no ROM developer I've ever heard of actually supports Xposed and the first step in troubleshooting any issues is remove it and clean flash. There is the issue of Xposed basically being dead in itself as well, still no Nougat support and it's not looking good... Meaning Android O and future support is unlikely either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a general rule to it. The Framework *might* be incompatible with some ROM, but I've never heard of such.¹ I've used it successfully on multiple devices running either "stock"² or CyanogenMod.

¹ Some *modules* however don't work well with specific devices/ROMs, or only with them. Examples are those written for a specific flavor (e.g. just for TouchWiz devices), or adding features from a specific custom ROM (and thus shouldn't be combined with that one).

² What is "stock"? In case of one of my devices, it is CyanogenOS. On Xiaomi devices, it's something with MIUI. On the OnePlus, it might be OxygenOS. For Samsung devices, it's something heavily modified including TouchWiz. So some ROMs (e.g. CyanogenMod/CyanogenOS) are even closer to AOSP than some "stock ROMs".

**Conclusion:** A generic answer is difficult. When in doubt, check for your specific combination (device & ROM) at XDA – either in the [XPosed area](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed), or in the section specific to your device.

**PS:** Also note that the "latest Android" is usually not (yet) supported by the Xposed framework. As of this writing, the latest supported Android version is 6.x.

Comment: You know, now that I think about it, "stock" in this situation probably means any ROM (that is rooted of course) that does does not have extensive features built into it (e.g., LMT, pie, graphical customization, etc.). So technically it may not be limited to ROMs that are specific to the device. I think as a general rule, custom ROMs probably don't bode well with Xposed framework, if they have extensive features.

Comment: @Narcotixs I cannot say so. As I wrote, on one hand I'm using it with CyanogenMod as well as CyanogenOS (both, if you so will, "custom ROMs" – while being close to AOSP, what you probably were pointing at) – and on the other hand I'd cosider Samsung's ROMs quite heavily modded, and there are even special Xposed modules for those. So hard to say where chances are best; in general, the closer to AOSP the more likely there are no (or only few) incompatibilities.